# SQL Query that Returns Number of Consecutive Login Dates for each User

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of users of varying ID's. The database contains a recording for each user and whether the user has logged in or not at on a specific date. The table contains recordings for every day.
I want to write an SQL query that returns all the instances where a user logs in for 3 or more consecutive days, alongside the user's id, the number of total consecutive days, and the start and end date for the log in streak. (Of course a user could have more than one streak)

The table would look something like this:

| id | logged_in | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1022 | Y | 7/11/2022 |
| 1022 | Y | 7/12/2022 |
| 1022 | N | 7/13/2022 |
| 1022 | Y | 7/14/2022 |
| 1022 | Y | 7/15/2022 |
| 1022 | Y | 7/16/2022 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2519 | Y | 8/20/2022 |
| 2519 | Y | 8/21/2022 |
| 2519 | Y | 8/22/2022 |
| 2519 | Y | 8/23/2022 |
| 2519 | Y | 8/24/2022 |
| 2519 | N | 8/25/2022 |

And the result:

| id | count | start date | end date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1022 | 3 | 7/14/2022 | 7/16/2022 |
| 2519 | 5 | 8/20/2022 | 8/24/2022 |

Thank you.

Comment: `SUM(date <> LAG(date)) as consecutive_group`

Comment: *Of course a user could have more than one streak* what would be your expected output in tis case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  One approach uses the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) rn1,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, logged_in ORDER BY date) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count, MIN(date) AS start_date, MAX(date) AS end_date
FROM cte
WHERE logged_in = 'Y'
ORDER BY id, rn1 - rn2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
SELECT ID,COUNT(looged_in),MIN(date),MAX(date) FROM TABLE WEHRE looged_in = "Y" 
GROUP BY ID
```

Hope the solution helps you

Comment: It produces wrong results if to add one more row with values `id = 1022`, `logged_in = 'Y'` and `date = '2022-7-10`  for example. Then you would get `id - 1022 COUNT - 6 MIN - 2022-07-10 MAX - 2022-07-16`, like if user logged in for 6 days consequentally (as counted), but there should be 2 rows one per group of 3 days

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).